# How do Jira's solutions relate to statuses by default?

Tags: jira

I have a shiny new Jira installation. Whenever I set my status to `Done` the resolution is also set to `Done`. I get that I should not edit the resolution field directly as described in [How to make the Resolution field editable?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Can-not-Edit-Resolution-Field/qaq-p/749848), but isn't there a default way to set it to `Won't Do` without changing my workflows?

Answer (score 2):

There is two common options and any of them includes you to change workflow:

1. Add screen which contains Resolution field into transition. If you want more flexible way and add ability for users to set this field when they perform transition.
2. Set Resolution from post-functions of transition. If you already know which resolution must be set in this transition.

Comment: So this means that there are solutions that cannot be reached by the default behavior? So why have them in the first place if there's no way to set them without changing some workflows anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by "default behavior"? You can setup one or another way for setting Resolution by change workflow settings and then users will be able to move issues through statuses with expected result.

Comment: I just baffles me that there are statuses inside of Jira that cannot be used right off the bat. Why have it there in the first place if I cannot use it?

Comment: @Semmel You are misunderstanding the concept of status and resolution. 
Statuses are used to represent the position of the issue in its workflow.
Resolutions are the ways in which an issue can be closed.

Comment: @bertperrisor That is precisely how I understand status and resolution. My point is: Why are there default resolutions that cannot be reached through any default status?

Comment: @Semmel There is no way they relate to each other by default. The resolutions are there for users to choose them when closing issues.

Not sure what issue you are facing, or what you are talking about by default behavior - this will definitely need post-function, as sintasy's has already cleared up.

Resolution is a global context and they apply to all projects. If you CANT change the resolution when resolving issues,(e.g it is always resolved as Done), then check your post-functions. Something is automatically setting the Resolution.

Comment: @bertperrisor This was really helpful! So - we should be able to chose the resolution upon resolving issues? I need to check why this is not the case.